# Why aren't completely random quantum states 'physical'?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, condensed-matter, quantum-states, randomness

I've come across the statement that 'completely random states are generically not 'physical', in the sense that they cannot be eigenstates of Hamiltonians with local interactions (in 1D)'.

Reference: Second paragraph of introduction in https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.01714

Why is it so? Aren't the spectral properties of a chaotic Hamiltonian well modeled by a random matrix class like GOE? Mid-spectrum eigenstates of local chaotic Hamiltonians are also expected to have volume-law entanglement entropy that matches the Page value according to the Eigenstate Thermalization Hypothesis.
What stops us from calling such eigenstates 'physical' or 'completely random'?

Comment: It will be helpful if you share a reference for that statement.

Comment: Thanks, I've added the reference.

Comment: You should quote a longer segment of the article text in your question as the article is pay-walled.

Comment: Ah my bad, I've changed the reference to the free arxiv version instead.

Answer (score 1):

The statement "Completely random states are generically not physical" only makes sense in a very specific context. An obvious counter example being the totally mixed state $\rho=I/d$ being "physical" as a thermal state at $\beta=0$.

Going to the reference, the authors are discussing *how* the eigenstate thermalization hypthosis (ETH) *could be* true. It's probably helpful to aim towards deciphering what they mean in the next sentence "For
the ETH to be a physical scenario for thermalization,
highly excited eigenstates of physical local Hamiltonians
cannot always be completely random, yet they have to
contain enough entropy".

Intuitively, ETH basically says that even a single energy eigenstate $|\Psi_n\rangle$ is actually enough to reproduce the predictions made by traditional stat-mech with ensembles like $\rho_{\mathrm{canonical}}:=e^{-\beta\hat H}/Z$.
One apparent difference between those two is that one has von-Neumann entropy $S_{\mathrm{vN}}:=-\mathrm{tr} (\rho\log\rho)$ that is $0$ while the other has $S_{\mathrm{vN}}$ that matches that of the Shannon entropy $S_{\mathrm{S}}:=-\sum_i p_i\log p_i$.

I think what the authors are trying to say after all, is simply that in order for ETH to hold, the single eigenstate must carry the right amount of fluctuations (or the information of such) so that it correctly reproduces predictions by stat-mech regarding entropy etc. This isn't possible by a *totally* random state.

You're comment regarding GOE states is a bit off of a counter example, since that's only about the spectral properties of a chaotic Hamiltonian. The authors here are talking about the individual eigen*state*, and the eigenvector of a GOE matrix does not resemble at all with a physical energy eigenstates of a chaotic quantum system.

One general comment I can make is that sometimes when a sentence in the introduction section of a paper is cryptic and is not really making sense, it could be more efficient to skip that part and understand what they actually do/calculate in that paper. Introductions tend to carry some "intuitive" arguments or motivation settings, that may be hard to grasp before you clearly understand what they *actually* did in the work. This seems to be the case for this sentence, to me.